# Can bool variable be NULL

Tags: variables

I want to know if bool variable can be null, or it must have to be true or false:

Base on Arduino description:
A bool holds one of two values, true or false. (Each bool variable occupies one byte of memory.)

Answer (score 2):

A `bool` value must be either `0` or `1`, or `false` and `true` respectively. It is [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120862/does-the-c-standard-allow-for-an-uninitialized-bool-to-crash-a-program) for it to be any other value. When assigning a value to a `bool`, the compiler will automatically force it to be 0 if it is already 0, or 1 if it is not.

However, as it is a full byte, it is possible to store another value. As mentioned before, however, this is undefined behavior. This means that if it ever happens, or will absolutely happen, the program can do *anything*: for example, crash the program, output random data, or act like it's truthy, falsy, or both! In fact, that *can* (again, no guarantees) happen if you store the value 2:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    union b_c {
        unsigned char c;
        bool b;
    };
    b_c c;
    c.c = 2;

    if(c.b) puts("true!");
    if(!c.b) puts("false!");
}
```

(this is designed to run on a computer, but the same thing could happen on an Arduino). [Check out what happens](https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/eM14v7srM) when you run it: it outputs both `true!` and `false!`! This obviously doesn't make sense, but because we violate the rules by making a `bool` `2`, we loose all guarantees.

---

So, how is this relevant to your question? There's no valid value a `bool` can store other than `true` and `false`. In C++, `null` is defined as "an integer literal with value zero". So, if you were to assign `null` to a `bool`, it would be stored as false. If you want a separate null value, you're better off using another type that takes up a single byte (e.g. `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, same thing) and storing e.g. `0` for `false`, `1` for `true`, and `2` for null.

Comment: just want to know if i am correct or not that bool is single bit can only hold 0 or 1

Comment: @Shahreza yes, you can only store a `0` or `1` in a `bool`, i.e. a single bit. However, because you can't address single bits, each `bool` takes up a full byte, even though you can't use the other 7 buts.

Comment: Depending on the compiler's implementation, a bool can also be as wide as an `int`. There is no guarantee that it takes just 8 bits (chapter 8.3.3 in the C++17 standard). However, some systems support bit accesses (8051 microcontroller, for example), and some compilers for these support 1-bit `bool`s.

Comment: A boolean test doesn't look only at bit 0 *in most implementations*; rather, it may look at the entire variable and test it's "zero-ness. Zero == false; non-zero == true. That still doesn't leave any values for a third distinct meaning (such as NULL). If you need that, an enum would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

A bool is literally that - a boolean value. So either 1 or 0 - true or false.

In C only pointers can be NULL. Every other primitive type is a value, and NULL is not a value.